# Python & regexp - returning integers from various lines then write then delimited by tab into a different file

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I get the following file every hour, only numbers will vary:

```
<text>
<......>
<smtng>1</smtn> #line 3
......
<smtngelse>5</smtngelse> #line 9
-----
</text>
```

The next file might have a 2 instead of 1 for example.

How can I return the numbers on line 3 and 9 delimited by tab then append them into a different file?

The result should be 15.

Thanks 
Diez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `beautifulsoup` for getting values from the xml, and then write results to the file in `a` (append) mode:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<text>
<smtng>1</smtng>
<smtngelse>5</smtngelse>
</text>
""")

value1 = soup.find('smtng').text
value2 = soup.find('smtngelse').text

with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('%s\t%s\n' % (value1, value2))
```

Hope that helps.